# Is it possible to create temporary collection in mongoDB like temp table in sql server?

Tags: mongodb, temporary

I Want to create a temp collection in mongodb just like temp table in Sql Server.If it is possible then please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use $out operator introduced in version 2.6, where you can write the output of your aggregation pipeline into a collection and use it as a temporary collection, which can be deleted after it served your purpose.

Here is the link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: Of course unlike SQL you will have make the `$out` collection name unique.  In SQL Server the temp table names are unique to the connection.

Answer (score 3):

No there are no temporary collections.

You may have a look at [capped collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) which "*are fixed-size collections*" and they behave like this:  "*once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the collection.*"

Comment: Capped collections satisfy a totally different use case.   I would not associate them with "temporary collections."